# Calculus by Spivak Chapter 24 Problem 1 part (ii)

Tags: calculus

> The functions $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are defined by
>   $$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases} 0& x\leq n, \\ x-n & x\geq n. \end{cases} $$
>   Give a rigorous proof that it does not converge uniformly.

What is the pointwise limit to this function?
Does it not exist?

I'm confused.

Comment: Draw a couple of these. You can see that the functions just slide to the right as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: These are functions that are $0$ up to $n$, then linearly ramp up with slope of $1$ beyond that point.  Hope that gets you on the right track.

Comment: How? If n goes to infinity how can you subtract infinity from infinity?

Comment: THe pointwise limit is zero. Do you see why?

Comment: The *pointwise* limit is just the constant $0$ function, but the convergence is not uniform on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @rajb245 No, that's only valid for fixed finite n.

Comment: @mixedmath As n gets bigger so does part of the interval for which f(x)=0 ?

Comment: You have a sequence of functions, each with a finite $n$.  Each one is zero up until $n$, then ramps up after that.  I am only describing the sequence of functions for you to visualize it.

Comment: @rajb245 Yeah, I could see that before posting, I'm still confused about how to prove mathematically that the pointwise limit is f(x)=0.

Comment: Pointwise convergence means pick a point, say $x_0$, and fix it.  Then take the limit.  So you give me a specific point $x_0$, and I can tell you confidently that $f_n(x_0)$ will be zero in the limit, no matter what fixed, large $x_0$ you take.  For any $x_0$, I pick $N>\text{ceil}(x_0)$ so that $f_N(x_0)=0$.  This is the definition of pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pointwise convergence.**  Choose some $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  Why is
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0\,?
$$
For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \ge x$, we have $x - n \le 0$, so $f_n(x) = 0$.  (The sequence of values $\{f_n(x), f_{n+1}(x), \ldots\}$ doesn't just get arbitrarily close to $0$.  It lands on $0$ and stays there.)

**Failure of uniform convergence.**  For any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have to be able to choose $N > 0$ *before choosing a particular* $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so that
$$
\big| f_n(x) - 0 \big| < \varepsilon \qquad \text{for all } n \ge N.
$$
This is clearly impossible since $x$ can be arbitrarily large and $f_n(x) = x - n$ can too.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking in reverse order, that is, what happens when x is infinity, but that's just something absurd since we are studying the relationship between x and n. I'm tired, I've been solving exercises since morning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For pointwise convergence, fix some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_0)$.  Choose any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $x_0\le N$.  Then, for all $n\ge N$, it follows that $x_0\le n$ so that $f_n(x_0)=0.$  In particular, this shows that $f_n(x)$ approaches $0$ pointwise.

Take $x_0=6.5$ for an explicit example.  Then $N=7$.  In this case we have:
$$\begin{align}f_0(6.5)&=6.5\\f_1(6.5)&=5.5\\f_2(6.5)&=4.5\\\vdots\\f_6(6.5)&=0.5\\f_7(6.5)&=0\\f_8(6.5)&=0\\\vdots\end{align}$$

Notice that the value reaches $0$ after finitely many steps, after which it remains $0$.

Now, a helpful way to think of uniform convergence is that as $n$ gets larger the sequence of functions tightly 'hugs' the limit function *along the entire domain*.  In our example, each $f_n(x)$ only 'hugs' the limit function $0$ for $x\le n$, and not for all $x$.

Explicitly, we say that $f_n$ converges to $0$ uniformly if for any $\varepsilon> 0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x)|<\varepsilon$ **for all** $x$ as long as $n\ge N$.  In our case, take $\varepsilon=1$, and notice that $|f_n(n+2)|=2>1$.  This shows that no matter how we choose $N$, there will always be values of $x$ that do not approximate $0$ for $n\ge N$.